# What belongs in the backend vs frontend?

Tags: frontend, backend

I'm not sure what is considered or what should be front vs backend. I guess the best way to demonstrate would be with a story.

> I am a [user] and I would like to have an account to show my personalized profile and save documents to my portfolio.

In this case, [user] needs to sign up and input desired info into their profile. Does this info (eg name, location, etc) belong in some sort of backend database or should it just be added to csv in my directory?

Maybe the answer to my question is "worry about this after the front-end is done"?

I am new to coding but I feel like I understand the basics. I'm building via Jekyll and probably bootstrap, on Github.

Comment: Rule of thumb - Backend: What runs and stored on server side. Frontend: What user sees and interacts with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question isn't really what Stack Overflow is about (which is answering questions about a specific technical problem you're having), but here's some insight for you anyways:

Front-end is what the user interacts with. Think of it like a paper application or a tax form where it has fields and instructions and maybe a worksheet to calculate values. Then you send in the paper form to some authority (this is like submitting a web form to the server).

Back-end saves and processes the form. They do heftier calculations, saves things to long-term storage, verifies data, etc. and returns successes or failures to the front-end.

You should definitely save your data to a database. Don't just write to a CSV file. CSV files are fine for small projects to practice and see the concept, but for production, a CSV file is not safe since anyone could access it easily whereas a database would have safety checks to deny or grant access.

Good luck with your learning!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll ask these types of questions elsewhere.

Comment: Wow! I really appreciate how you broke that down. That made it super easy to understand. I kinda figured csv wasn't the way to go. You make a good point about security.